# Unattended upgrade returned: False

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm getting this email from several computers on our network. Any idea what I need to do?

```
Unattended upgrade returned: False

Packages that attempted to upgrade:
 firefox firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer 
 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gnome-calculator gnome-panel gnome-panel-data 
 gnome-session-flashback libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common 
 liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 libpanel-applet-4-0 
 oxideqt-codecs-extra python-cupshelpers python-requests 
 python3-requests system-config-printer-common 
 system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev wpasupplicant 

Unattended-upgrades log:
Initial blacklisted packages: 
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: ['origin=Canonical,suite=trusty', 'origin=Ubuntu,suite=trusty-security', 'origin=Ubuntu,suite=trusty-updates']
Packages that are auto removed: ''
Packages that will be upgraded: firefox firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gnome-calculator gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-session-flashback libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 libpanel-applet-4-0 oxideqt-codecs-extra python-cupshelpers python-requests python3-requests system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev wpasupplicant
Writing dpkg log to '/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg_2014-10-15_10:56:47.744158.log'
Internal error while building a minimal partition.Cache has not allowed changes
```

And this is the content of the log file:

```
(Reading database ... 357633 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rsyslog_7.4.4-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rsyslog (7.4.4-1ubuntu2.3) over (7.4.4-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up rsyslog (7.4.4-1ubuntu2.3) ...
The user `syslog' is already a member of `adm'.
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
rsyslog stop/waiting
rsyslog start/running, process 6982
```

If it matters:

```
#uname -a
Linux xxxxx 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Thanks for the -1, but I'd also appreciate if you could share your criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message was misleading. The problem was that the `apt-get upgrade` command wanted to show some changelogs, and since it was and automatic upgrade, there was no `tty` and a user to accept the changes, hence this error/email happened.

An interactive `sudo apt-get upgrade` and accepting the changes solved the problem.